# CSS nav bar: extend spacer div to fill remaining width without overflow:hidden trick

Tags: css, width, overflow

**strong text**Seems like a common problem, but in my case it's complicated by a few extra requirements, so what I found on SO and MDN didn't lead me to a full solution.

Simple premise: 
Horizontal nav bar, full width of the page, semi-transparent background, variable number of tabs (extra space filled with same background as tabs).

Easy, right? Give the container element `rgba` background, set nav items `display:inline` or `float` them left and you're golden.

**Complication 1: Active tab has to have a triangular cutout (see pic).**

Ok, I can have a cutout by setting background-image to a png with transparent bit. The background of the parent element would get in the way - so set background to individual elements instead of parent.

What about the variable width "empty space" past the tabs (see pic)? Ok, put an empty element with a larger than life width, and cut it off with `overflow:hidden` on the parent.

**Complication 2:**

Buttons need tooltips on hover.
Ah, the thrill! The suspense! `overflow:hidden` won't do unless I put tooltips outside of nav div altogether (which would probably work - but seems smelly).

[image: nav screenshot]

So, here are a few things I tried:

Old implementation which doesn't have the "filler" element width problem but clips off half a tooltip (with overflow:hidden):
http://codepen.io/istro/pen/aHcdi

Messing with `display:table` seems to give little control over how `display:table-cell` div width is decided, also needs content to display the div in the first place. Content can be moved away, but still no good (didn't even add a tooltip here):
http://codepen.io/istro/pen/uIcfn

Messing with floats (tooltip sorta where I'd want it to be more or less), but clueless how to make the last "filler" element fit remaining width:
http://codepen.io/istro/pen/aIGxB

So the question - **how could I make a div to fill the remaining width with CSS only? Or perhaps I'm asking the wrong question altogether, in which case what ideas would I use to implement it cleanly?**

Thanks!!!

Comment: Do you mind a solution using flexbox layout?

Comment: Nope, it's an internal tool, so I can dictate which browser is supported :). However looking at a guide - http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ - I didn't notice an obvious way to apply it to my situation...